# SSH AWS Ec2 key authentication fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty, git-bash

In my Ec2 instance i have changed my keypair, by manually adding the new public key from the keypair. When i tried to login as ec2-user it' asking for password.

When i ran in debug mode(ssh -vvv -i ec2-user@ip) it's shows that

```
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

Then it goes for password validation.

But for a successful login the response is

```
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue. Because when i tried to loging using putty by converting the `.pem` to `.ppk` it's working but not working from Git Bash.

Comment: After `-i` you need to specify the location of your keypair. Can you share the complete command you are trying?

Comment: sorry @KrishnaKumarR i fjust forget to give it here. But i tried like `ssh -vvv -i filelocation ec2-user@x.x.x.x` only.

Comment: why you have down voted my question. It's really a issue i faced and any way i solved it.

Comment: I downvoted your question because it doesn’t provide any detail beside "I can't connect". We can’t magically guess your issue if you don’t provide more info.

Comment: @bfontaine what additional information i have to give, other than ip address and .pem/.ppk file i have given all the details, i don't what more additional details you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, the thing is my team member created the public key from the private key(EC2 keypair) by using putty and updated in EC2, and the public key that EC2 have is a different one, so it's going well with putty and not bash, anyway thanks @KrishnaKumarR for your help.